# retrofit and constant parameters in requests

Tags: java, android, rest, retrofit

In many REST API's there is need to set up parameter "key" in requests. I.e. Google's YouTube API.
I know that there is standard way to use "@Query" in requests, but you should add this "@Query" in every function.
Is there any way to override method or class to add something like "setEndpoint" but for parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the parameter is always set to the same value you can use a `RequestInterceptor`:

```
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
        .setEndpoint(API_END_POINT)
        .setRequestInterceptor(new RequestInterceptor() {
            @Override
            public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
                request.addQueryParam("api_eky", API_KEY);
            }
        })
        .build();
```

However, if the parameter is only set for some requests, I prefer to keep those in the method signatures of the service interface and define them in a singleton API client class as class member variables and pass the parameter value into the RestAdapter methods that require it.